# How to make a random data driven test from CSV file by Jmeter

Tags: csv, random, jmeter, data-driven-tests

I have a csv file with a number of rows, and each row has this format:

```
name,surname,fathername,email,password,phone,longitude,latitude,address,postcode
```

I would like to create a Jmeter data driven test which should use the variables from this rows. I have no problem with it, but I would like to improve it and I want Jmeter to make his own test data from this file. So it should for each request take not a random row but every variable. Do you know the easiest way to do it using 1 csv file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. The easiest is to have separate CSV files for each value and then use the random feature. The alternative is to do it programmatically.

Edit: Sorry I missed the part where you said 1 CSV file. :-(

Comment: @automatioguy Hi,thank you for your answer. Can you help me with the second way?